# How to move an image object

Tags: javascript

This is my code. If I initialize an object with imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage'); everything is working but with imgObj = "bird3.png"; the animation does'nt happen. Any ideas?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var imgObj = null;
        var animate;

        function init(){

           imgObj = new Image();
           imgObj = "bird3.png";
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight(){
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
        }

        function stop(){
           clearTimeout(animate);
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        window.onload =init;

  </script>
```

```
  <form>
     <img id="myImage" src="bird3.png" />
     <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
     <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
     <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't imgObj = "bird3.png"; be imgObj.src = "bird3.png";...

Comment: Open your developer console. It will tell you when you have errors.

Comment: Guys he try to animate a variable in javascript..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Me? He sets the variable to a string, and then accesses `.style.position`. It will give him an "undefined does not have property..." error, or whatever it is. Hence, open the console.

Comment: I know that will be resolved with first comment (noted in my answer), but that not the main problem, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate an object that is not yet added to `DOM`, you just create an `Image object` without affect it to any container in page, so you have to append it to an element then try to move it.

It's work with `imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');` because you select an element that is already on `DOM`.

**NOTE :** take a look at @Danton comment it's true you must add `.src`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the grab the image in the page and not create a new one.
replace:
           imgObj = new Image();
           imgObj = "bird3.png";

with:
imgObj = document.getElementById("myImage");